# Publish Sheet add-on always shows dialog "Go to the G Suite Marketplace SDK..."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, add-on

I have configured the "Google Workspace Marketplace SDK" configuration panel. My app is internal to my organization domain, hopefully won't need any OAuth review nor the app preview.

When I click the `Publish-->Deploy as add-on`

[image]

it always shows a dialog box

> Go to the G Suite Marketplace SDK. If you are publishing a new add-on follow this guide. To update an existing add-on follow these steps.

I have connected my Apps Script with GCP standard project, configured the scopes everywhere.

Who can tell me what to do next steps? I want to to publish an internal (private use only) add-on.

---

Btw, the "G Suite Marketplace API" doesn't have a place to configure apps publication, I did it from the "Google Workspace Marketplace SDK". They are super confusing names...

Answer (score 0):

After you finished your "*App Configuration*" screen for Google Workspace Marketplace SDK (which is opened by default when you click "open SDK" link from Apps Script editor) you also need to make sure your listing is created - this may need to be done just once on initial add-on publishing.

Click on "*Store Listing*", make sure you filled all required sections, and submit the form.

After successful form submit you will be able to see your listing status:

[image]